# Cascading not working on delete with Spring Data JPA Repositories

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I'm having a constraint issue when trying to delete an object containing a OneToMany relationship which should not be happening. I've set `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`, tried adding the Hibernate specific `@Cascade` annotation, tried rebuilding a new database, and I even created the minimal example below all of which fail.

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test-db`.`bar`, CONSTRAINT `FKdvoqij212wwl2bf14kwo55h55` FOREIGN KEY (`foo_id`) REFERENCES `foo` (`id`))
```

Object to be cascaded

```
@Entity
public class Bar {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Foo foo;

    // Constructor, getters and setters omitted
}
```

Class containing cascading

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Bar> bars;

    // Constructor, getters and setters omitted
}
```

Test:

```
// Spring Data JPA Repositories (extend CrudRepository)
@Autowired private FooRepository fooRepository;
@Autowired private BarRepository barRepository;

@Test
public void test() {
    final Foo foo = new Foo();
    fooRepository.save(foo);

    final Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.setFoo(foo);
    barRepository.save(bar);

    fooRepository.delete(foo);
}
```

This test above fails. I'd expect to be able to delete Foo without having to delete all associated Bar objects as cascading was set on the OneToMany relationship. Why is this failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)`

Comment: also try `foo.getBars().add(bar)` in your tests to make sure the bi-directional relationship is established properly.

Comment: That fixed it. Does this mean I need to add the associations to both objects to maintain a bi-directional relationship? I figured if I added the `Foo` object to the `Bar` object, it'd automatically create a bi-directional relationship.

Comment: Also, add your comment containing `foo.getBars().add(bar)` to the main answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: The relationship should be established in the DB side, however the foo object in memory hasn't been updated. I think if you were to re-query for foo after saving bar, the list will have the bars Collection updated, and you can delete successfully.

Comment: You're right. I re-queried for foo and then deleted and it worked. Add all of your comments to your answer and I'll accept. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The "cascade.remove" and "orphanRemoval" are two diffrent operation.

Comment: it is exactly same as question :|